# Maximal number of subsets formed by subsets of a fixed Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to find maximal number of subsets formed by $n$ subsets of a fixed set Using intersection, union and complement operations. I've already encountered something close to it in maths logic, and I guess it might be solved by producing $2^n$ formulae utilizing one of those three operators (let it be intersection), which represent prepositions(just like maxterms in logic), like, for example $x\in X$ or $x\in\bar X$. In fact they would look something like $X_1^{\epsilon1}\cap...\cap X_n^{\epsilon n}$, with $\epsilon$ being some subset in set of all consequences ($\epsilon_1...\epsilon_n)$ and $X_i^\epsilon$ being either $X_i$ or $\bar X_i$
. But then again, I know the formula will be $2^{2^{n}}$, so the first question is, how to derive it from the number of intersection formulae? 
I'd like to give an example of such formulae: if $n = 2$. Let $A = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$. Considering $X_1 = \{ 1, 2 \}$ и $X_2 = \{ 1, 3 \}$. Then $X_1 \cap X_2 = \{ 1 \}$, $X_1 \cap\bar X_2 = \{ 2 \}$, $\bar X_1 \cap X_2 = \{ 3 \}$,$\bar X_1 \cap \bar X_2 = \{ 4 \}$.

The second question is, how do I *prove* that there will be $2^n$ intersection formulae for this case? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a given set of $n$ subsets, you may or may not be able to get many subsets by combining them using intersection, complement and union. But there exist sets of $n$ subsets that do give you $2^n$ subsets just by combining them with unions. Consider the set of all singleton sets $\{i\}$ where $i\in [1..n]$. You can combine subsets from this set using just the union operation to get any subset of $[1..n]$ you desire, and we know there are $2^n$ different subsets of $[1..n]$.

Comment: But how about $2^{2^{n}}$ subsets formed by $n$ subsets? I'm pretty sure that is the correct formula.

Comment: I mean, I do understand they could either be included or not, each negation of a singleton subset giving us a new subset right till $2^{2^{n}}$,, hence the finla formula is $2^{2^{n}}$, but, how can it be proven formally?